# Typings file for OfficeJs 1.3

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm developing a Word AddIn using typescript. Now I would like to try out some features of the 1.3 api. Is the 1.3 version of the typings file available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of APIs marked with "WordApi 1.3 Beta" on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/office-js/office-js.d.ts.  Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: It is. I didn't look into the file and concluded after not finding one thing that it must be because of a 1.2 version.